# How do I plot magnetic field lines from computational data with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I've got files with cartesian data - a collection of points each coming with 3 coordinates and 3 magnetic field components. I need to visualize this data as 2D plots with magnetic field lines.

How do I do that? What manipulations do I have to do with the original data to be able to plot those vector lines? And what would the gnuplot commands look like?

Answer (score 1):

The command to plot the entire data set as vectors is simple:

```
set style arrow 1 head filled linewidth 0.5
splot 'data' using 1:2:3:4:5:6 with vectors arrowstyle 1
```

This assumes that the vector components are given in the same units as your axis coordinates; otherwise you would have to add a scale factor (e.g. replace `4:5:6` with `($4 * scale):($5*scale):($6*scale)` However this will generate a 3D plot that may well be too complicated to interpret visually in 2D projection.  You might simplify it by specifying a projection along the z axis and then filtering to select only the points in a particular slice of z values:

```
set view map    # projection along z
filter(z) = ((zlow < z && z < zhigh) ? z : NaN)
splot 'data' using 1:2:(filter($3)):4:5:6 with vectors arrowstyle 1
```

More complicated representations that combine the vectors with contours of an associated magnitude are possible.  Have a look at the on-line demo [vector dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/vector.html) for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The problem is however that I need to plot the magnetic field lines, which are tangent to the vector field at each point; the ''density'' of those lines would represent the magnitude of the vectors and the lines themselves represent the geometry of the field. It seems that I can't do that with just ''raw'' input data (x,y and corresponding vector components at some fixed z), but I don't know what data would gnuplot be able to plot those lines with.